# .net framework system calls and cross platform capabilities

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, mono, cross-platform

I know this question sounds silly, so please let me explain. I've been learning how to program in c# on windows, and have been doing pretty well. One thing i've realized recently though is that i'm not really sure how it works. I know the basics, for example, i know that c# gets compiled to CIL, or MSIL. that is then run though a JIT compiler that produces that native code that is actually run. 
My confusion happens when we look at the cross platform capabilities of .net framework though.
From my study of other languages on other platforms such as C on linux, i've learned about system calls and how system calls are necessary anytime a program uses a hardware system such as the hard drive. Now, in C on linux, when you call a function like `fopen()`, the C standard library on linux ends up eventually making a system call to linux to perform the actual work of `fopen()`. Once the OS is done, it returns to the calling program. 
Now, i imagine that c#/.net framework is similar correct? So when I type `file.open(something);` it somehow ends up calling into the win32 API, and that handles the operation and then returns to the program. is this assumption correct?
If that is correct though, then how is c# cross platform at all? if when i write `file.open();` it calls into the win32 api, how is it that it can run just fine in mono on linux? If it calls the win32 API on linux, it should fail because that doesn't exist there.
 So is it the .net framework library that calls into the OS API, similar to C? or is it the JIT compiler that does the actual call when the final compilation takes place, depending on what platform it's running on? 
So is the final pipeline something like this? -> 
-c#, file.open(something) gets compiled to -><
-MSIL, equivalent command in MSIL language, gets compiled to ->
-native code, calls into OS API, either win32 API or linux API via system call
(I'm just asking for a rough overview of the process, no in depth details needed) 
Secondly, when the developers of mono where creating Mono, did they just have to go one class at a time, method by method, through the entire .net framework library and have to recreate it to work on linux? Because that would be A LOT of work.
Thank you

Comment: About Mono, you can find some rough history from posts like [this](https://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/history/). Because .NET Framework was not open sourced, they had to reimplement each classes one by one like you mentioned. That's why it took Mono many years to finally reach its prime days (like captured in [this](https://www.mono-project.com/archived/roadmap_history/) and [this](https://corefx.lextudio.com/)). Definitely that's a lot of work, but empowering success like Unity/Xamarin makes that process worth the while.

Comment: "how is C# cross platform at all" - C# does not have any methods to open files or generally interact with OS... So Language by itself is perfectly compatible with  any OS (or even lack of OS as normally understood)...

Answer (score 1):

The file system is an operating system resource, I/O methods in both .NET Core and .NET Framework wrap calls to the underlying operating system.
Below is the picture that explains how .NET works with non-.NET code (using CCW & RCW).

[image]

Ref: [managed-code-and-unmanaged-code-in-net](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/puranindia/managed-code-and-unmanaged-code-in-net/)

Here is another image that might help understand what is available on which platform
[image]

Ref: [cross-platform-capabilities-of-dot-net](https://headspring.com/2018/07/10/cross-platform-capabilities-of-dot-net/)

Now what we need to understand is if you are using any features from .NET's Base Class Libraries, They are implemented to make appropriate calls based on which platform it's running.
However, if you are building an application that should support any platform then there are certain things that we must take care

There are two main requirements for making your software platform-agnostic:

1. Don’t use any APIs that are not implemented across other platforms
   (including Base Class Library methods that are not implemented
   outside of Windows and PInvoke calls to Windows-only libraries).
2. Properly treat file and folder paths so that platform-specific path
   separators (i.e., “\” and “/”) are not used explicitly.

If you really want to understand how CLR works, I would Highly recommend the book [image]http://sd.blackball.lv/library/CLR_via_CSharp_(Jeffrey_Richter_4th_Edition).pdf

Reference:

https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/puranindia/managed-code-and-unmanaged-code-in-net/
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/io/handling-io-errors
https://headspring.com/2018/07/10/cross-platform-capabilities-of-dot-net/